Google Sheets Formula Filter Combined Values - Separated by Comma's
I am currently working on creating a formula in Google Sheets that can filter both individual values and multiple values combined with commas.
I am facing challenges in understanding how to achieve this as my attempts so far have only produced results for individual values.
Your help will be much appreciated in this regards.
=FILTER(B:B,
  (D:D = J2) *
  REGEXMATCH(","&C:C&",", ",(" & SUBSTITUTE(I2, ",", "|,|") & "),")
)



try:
=FILTER(B:B, D:D=G2, REGEXMATCH(C:C, JOIN("|", TRIM(SPLIT(F2, ",")))))

or for case-insensitive:
=FILTER(B:B, D:D=G2, REGEXMATCH(C:C, "(?i)("&JOIN("|", TRIM(SPLIT(F2, ",")))&")"))


Now it seems easy :) Thank you very much for the help! @player0

@HSHO also be aware that C14 (or values with ' or parenthesis) from your image could cause regex to fail

You're right i will take care of this.
